# Enumerate paragraphs of a text

Tags: python, file, text, numbers, enumerate

I have a text divided into paragraphs but I would like to number these paragraphs (starting from 1, not 0).

For example I had this:

```
Easter eggs,
Yellow and blue,
Easter eggs,
For me and you.


Easter eggs,
Candy sweet,
Easter eggs,
Are good to eat.
```

If I give the program a line (or some word of the text) I want it to tell me which paragraph it is in, for example if I give:

```
Candy sweet
```

I want:

```
2
```

I want to implement this feature in my little translation program. in fact I would like that given a small sentence the program knows how to give translation and then the number of the paragraph. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to turn the string into a list and then check if the text is in the list element by element, if that makes sense.

```py
text = '''Easter eggs,
Yellow and blue,
Easter eggs,
For me and you.


Easter eggs,
Candy sweet,
Easter eggs,
Are good to eat.'''

search = input("Text To Be Searched: ")

split_lst = text.split("\n\n")
count = 1

for i in split_lst:
    if search in i:
        print(count)
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to define what is a paragraph, let's say that it means there is an empty line between two parts of a text. This is equal to `\n\n`, or `os.linesep * 2`.
Now, you can split the text into paragraphs using `split`.
The last part is to search the given sub-text, we can iterate over the paragraphs from `split` and find if the sub-text exists or not.
It will look like this

```py
import os

TEXT = """...."""

def get_sentence_location(sentence):
    paragraph_seperator = os.linesep * 2
    paragraphs = TEXT.split(paragraph_seperator)
    for index, paragraph in enumerate(paragraphs):
        if sentence in paragraph:
            return index + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in enumerate(<iterate_here, start=1):
    print(i)
```

Just use keyword argument on enumerate function.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`string.split()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html)

```
s = """
Easter eggs,
Yellow and blue,
Easter eggs,
For me and you.


Easter eggs,
Candy sweet,
Easter eggs,
Are good to eat."""
```

```py
to_be_found = 'Candy sweet'

for index, paragraph in enumerate(s.split('\n\n')):
    if to_be_found in paragraph:
        print(index+1)
```